# Swift enum, get raw value from associated enum

Tags: swift, enums

I wanted to make an enum which would carry all the `UserDefaults` keys in my app.

```
enum UserDefaultsKeys: String {
 case isLoggedIn
 case rememberLoginEmail 
}
```

At the same time I wanted it to be categorised as well so that one enum does not have too many keys from different modules, so I did this:

```
enum UserDefaultsKeys {
    case session(key: UserSessionKeys)
    case userPreference(key: UserPreferenceKeys)

    func key() -> String{
        switch self {

        case .session(let key):
            return key.rawValue

        case .userPreference(let key):
            return key.rawValue
        }
    }
}

enum UserSessionKeys: String {
    case isLoggedIn
}

enum UserPreferenceKeys: String {
    case rememberLoginEmail
}
```

I can access the raw value now by this: `UserDefaultsKeys.session(key: .isLoggedIn).key()`

It seems that I had to write a whole another function to get the raw value from an associated enum type. I feel there could be a better way for this, any suggestions?

Comment: I have a suggestion for you to have access to all user default values in a very Swifty and type safe way and that is to use `PropertyWrapper`.

Comment: Your question is very specific to `enum`, change your question to more general question and let me know if you need a hand for that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to mix enum with static constants

```
enum UserDefaultsKeys {
    enum Session {
        static let isLoggedIn = "key1"
        static let ...
    }

    enum Preferences {
        static let rememberLoginEmail = "key2"
    }
}
```

and then access them via their paths

```
let isLoggedInKey = UserDefaultsKeys.Session.isLoggedIn
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using such a solution

```
enum UserDefaultsKeys {
  case abstractContainer(key: KeyContainer)

  var key: String {
    switch self {
      case .abstractContainer(let key):
        return key.rawValue
    }
  }
}
protocol KeyContainer {
  var rawValue: String { get }
}

enum UserSessionKeys: String, KeyContainer {
  case isLoggedIn
}

enum UserPreferenceKeys: String, KeyContainer {
  case rememberLoginEmail
}

let u = UserDefaultsKeys.abstractContainer(key: UserSessionKeys.isLoggedIn)
print(u.key)
```

use only one abstract case and protocol instead of several items